# My Raycast2D is registering when facing one side but when going the other direction nothing is "hit."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I just did some bug fixing and found a bug that I cannot seem to figure out. My 2D character attacks and at the end of the animation it calls the function DealDamage(). The problem is that when my player is facing right and is attacking an enemy to its right it works perfectly fine. When it is facing left its as if the enemy is not there and there is "nothing" to hit. I checked and the Raycast returns null so it doesn't even register the enemy. I used DrawRaycast and the Raycast clearly hits the enemy. I don't know what to do.

```
public void DealDamage()
     {
         if (facingRight == true && weaponReach < 0)
         {
             weaponReach *= -1;
         }
         else if (facingRight == false && weaponReach > 0)
         {
             weaponReach *= -1;
         }

         RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin.position, new Vector2(weaponReach, 0), weaponReach, whoIsEnemy);
         if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == 12)
         {
             EnemyHealth EnemHealth = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
             EnemHealth.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
         }
     }
```

When I make the Raycasthit2D the following code everything magically works fine. The problem is that the distance is unlimited and I definitely don't want the player to hit the enemy a mile away.

```
 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin.position, new Vector2(weaponReach, 0), weaponReach, whoIsEnemy);
```

I expect that both sides to work perfectly fine and the same way.

Comment: The line that "magically works" isn't different to the one in the code above...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld say the issue is that when you are facing left you pass in a **negative** value `weaponReach` as `distance` to the raycast. In this case it will simply use `0` since a distance can not be negative.

---

You should separate the direction from the distance since the direction can be a normalized vector anyway:

```
// for the direction you actually only
// need a normalized vector either
// pointing right or left 
var direction = Vector2.right * (facingRight ? 1 : -1);
```

This is a shorthand form of writing

```
var distance = new Vector2(1, 0);
if(facingRight)
{
    // Actually you could ofcourse also 
    // completely skip that case
    direction *= 1;
}
else
{
    direction *= -1;
}
```

And then in the raycast always pass in a positive `weaponReach` as distance but in either a positive or negative `direction`

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin.position, direction, weaponReach, whoIsEnemy);

// You then should always check
if(hit != null)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Btw isn't your check

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == 12)
```

redundant since you already cast the raycast only on a certain layermask `whoIsEnemy` ?

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to have fixed the issue! Yup, I just realized it is kind of redundant and changed it to if(hit != false) since hit actually returns as a boolean.

Comment: then you can just use `if(hit)` ;) I often prefer the `null` variant since code analizer like e.g. ReSharper don't recognize that `if(hit)` actually equals `if(hit != null)` so I get a `PossibleNullReference Warning` ;) so it was just my habit